# Django how to know which button is clicked in case I have many buttons?

Tags: html, django, button

For an online shopping website, I have many products where each product contains an add to cart button, I want to know which button was clicked to know which product is related to that button.
I am new at Django and frontend so I think it is common but I don't know what does that and should it be javascript?

```
<div class="row">
    {% for product in products %}
        <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img alt="" class="thumbnail" src="{{ product.images.all.0.image.url }}">
            <div class="box-element product">
                <h5><strong>{{ product.name }}</strong></h5>
                <hr>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn"> Add to cart</button>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="{% url 'detail' %}"> View</a>
                <h4 style=" float: right"><strong>{{ product.price }}</strong></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Model(product in this case) has a unique id field related to it which Django automatically creates upon time of model migrations, if you haven't mentioned a primary key on model explicitly. In this case You will need javascript and eventhandlers that listen to Add to cart button click event.Below are some Steps with which you can achieve this i know these are some tedious things to do but give it a try.

**1. Create a javascript cart.js: this will add eventlistener to click event of each add to cart button.**

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart') //get all add to cart button with class update-cart

for (i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) { //iterate all add button to add eventlistener
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ //add eventlistener click for each button and set a function which will be executed on click
        var productId = this.dataset.product //get product id from attribute product set in html
        var action = this.dataset.action    //get action based on which you can handle remove or add to cart conditions
        console.log('productId:', productId, 'Action:', action)
        updateUserOrder(productId, action) // this function will be called and will pass product id and action in body to your view for further processing.
    })
}


function updateUserOrder(productId, action){ // this function will actually be called when someone click on add to cart button and view will be invoked
        var url = '/update_item/' // setting the url to be called

        fetch(url, {      //here we are using post request to post id of product and other details to our view
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
            }, 
            body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId, 'action':action})
        })
        .then((response) => {
           return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            location.reload()
        });
}
```

**2. Include the javascript in your html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/cart.js' %}"></script>
```

**3.Adding Eventhandler to add_to_cart button in yout htm** so whenever it is clicked you have to do the add functionality.
for this first thing you need to do is add a class "update-cart" to add button by which we will identify the add button on page
then you need some custom attributes by setting data- in this case it will be
product whose value will be id of a particular product like data-product="{{product.id}}" and add an action attribute to let us know when this button
is clicked we need to add a product to cart like data-action="add".
so now button code in html will look Something like this:

```
<button data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add" class="update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
```

**4.Create a corresponding view name 'update_item' which will be called from javascript whenever add button is clicked and will add item to cart**

```
def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print('Action:', action)
    print('Product:', productId)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId) # get product with selected id from database 
    #rest here add your logic for adding specific product to cart
```

**5.    Create a Route to updateItem view named update_item:**

```
path('update_item/', views.updateItem, name="update_item"),
```

Comment: Glad to here that :)